# How to fix for loop as it is returning only last iteration

Tags: r

I have a list of pdfs and list of keywords, each keyword should run through each pdf and return TRUE if it exists in the pdf

Tried with two `for` loops but its returning only last keyword and the result also incorrect, all are returning as TRUE. Only one pdf contains that word but it is showing TRUE for all the pdfs

```
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(tm)
library(filesstrings)
library(RODBC)


setwd("C:/RProject/ReadPDF/InputFiles/")

 SelectFirstKeyword <- list("new formula" , "new research", "morning up")



 ID  <- list.files("C:/RProject/ReadPDF/InputFiles/", full.names = T)

 ID_ <- ID[ID != ""]

 files   <- ID_


 for(i in 1:length(files)){

         for(j in 1:length(SelectFirstKeyword)){



           filename <- files[i]
           read <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))

           mystring <- Corpus(URISource(filename), readerControl = list(reader = read))

           lower_string <- tolower(mystring)
           CleanData  <- gsub("\n", " ",lower_string)

           second_string <- tolower(SelectFirstKeyword[j])
           print(second_string)

           mystring <- paste(CleanData,sep=" ")
           mystring_vector <- str_split(CleanData, "!")[[1]]

           FirstMatch <- second_string

           Match1 <- grepl(FirstMatch,mystring_vector[1])

           mystring <- paste(CleanData,sep=" ")
           mystring_vector <- str_split(CleanData, "!")[[1]]

           FirstMatch <- second_string

           Match1 <- grepl(FirstMatch,mystring_vector[1])


          FinalOutput <- paste(pdf_list,Outid, Match1)

          View(FinalOutput)


            if (Match1 == TRUE)
            {
                DATA1  <- paste(ID = pdf_list, Outid = FirstMatch , Keywordinnote = Match1)


            }

     }
}

View(DATA1)

### I shall email you the pdf files
```

Expected output is:

```
ID  outid       keywordinnote
1   news        TRUE
2   new formula TRUE
```

Comment: The answer to your question, how to fix, is put a bunch of print() statements in your code, see what each variable does at each point, and run on a small reproducible example.

Comment: yes, tried with that, I can see list of keywords are passing through loop one by one, but final result is wrong

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? At the moment we don't have anything to run your code on, plus there's lot of extra bits of code (like the whole `tryCatch()`)

Comment: @Phil, I have modified the code which the can be executed in RStudio, input files are sent to your e-mail id. Thanks

Comment: Anyone has a suggestion for this issue?